Open file descriptor limit in java and gradle on MacOS
File descriptor limit in java is lower than system default.
ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getMaxFileDescriptorCount() // 14848

despite:
ulimit -n                                # 32768
sysctl -a | grep kern.maxfiles:          # 245760
sysctl -a | grep kern.maxfilesperproc:   # 122880
launchctl limit maxfiles                 # maxfiles    32768          unlimited


For gradle task added: jvmArgs += ["-XX:-MaxFDLimit"] : this raised the limit from 10240 to 12544
In gradle.proparties added org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:-MaxFDLimit : this raised the limit from 12544 to  14848

Both are increments of 2304. What limit can be preventing 32768 from being used and where did those other values come from?
